# What is CallbackPath in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I need to create an endpoint that matches the configured CallBackPath to make the OpenId Authentication work. But I do not understand what is the use of it?

Will be great if someone can explain it?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "CookieScheme";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GoogleOpenIDScheme";
}
).AddOpenIdConnect("GoogleOpenIDScheme", options=>
{
    options.Authority = "https://XXXXXXXX";
    options.ClientId = "XXXXXXXX";
    options.ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    options.CallbackPath = "/Security/AuthOpenId";
}
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the user is authenticated at the authorization server, the user is redirected back to the client application so that the client can finalize the "flow".

The **CallbackPath** represents the URL to which the browser should be redirected to and the default value is **/signin-oidc**.

The picture below shows how it is related:

[image]

Comment: I understand what you said, But in the code I use the following method to redirect to the oidc provider

return new ChallengeResult(provider, new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = redirectUrlFinal });

The breakpoint at /signin-oidc is not hitting anyway.

But if the /signin-oidc method does not exist the program will throw an exception.

It's a bit strange to me. :)

It works and  after successful login it came back to redirectUrlFinal.

Comment: in your code you have options.CallbackPath = "/Security/AuthOpenId";  and the request to /Security/AuthOpenId is usually handled internally by the OpenIDConnect handler, and you don't normally se it happen as a developer. so you can't put a breakpoint on that request.  But you ycan see if if you use a tool like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler )

Comment: You also need to configure client.RedirectUris in identityserver to point to /Security/AuthOpenId

Comment: Thanks for the replay, /Security/AuthOpenId is usually handled internally by the OpenIDConnect handler, and you don't normally se it happen as a developer. This makes sense.

Comment: Yes, because the authentication handler captures the requests before it reaches MVC.